# Fetching Data from mca.gov.in using curl and PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch the data from http://mca.gov.in. I am using CURL and PHP for extracting the data.

Here is the form : http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/viewSignatoryDetails.do

When I do the HTML form submit directly through this HTML form to ( "http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/viewSignatoryDetails.do"), it works.

I developed my own form and submitted directly to the above link and it works too.

However, when I pass the same parameters to retrieve the data using `curl`, it is not giving any data.

Here is the code I am using to fetch the data from http://mca.gov.in.

```
$data = http_build_query($post_data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/viewSignatoryDetailsAction.do"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Any idea, what could be wrong or If I have missed anything ?

Comment: the site has captcha, how do u bypass that ?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that the url you are trying to fetch uses a captcha and you cannot bypass this by code.

You need to use a this url "***http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/popupSignatories.do***" that does not require a captcha.

So change your code to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/popupSignatories.do");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "companyid" => "AAA-4416"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Additionally if you want the company details, use ***"http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/companyMasterDataPopup.do"***

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/companyMasterDataPopup.do"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "method" => "ajaxGetCompanyMasterData",
    "companyid" => 'AAA-4416'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

### Update

There are some new APIs that can be found at [company master data API](https://data.gov.in/catalog/company-master-data) from https://data.gov.in

Comment: Hello @Jannes Botis, you wouldnt believe, after posting this question, I actually used the same approach(by scouting through the JS files). Thank you so much for the code as well. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: @Kiran how did you get the url http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/popupSignatories.do ?? I mean I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @Kiran Can you share the final working code if possible please